# Identify css selector string vs XPath string

Tags: javascript, html, css, xpath

I'm working on a small querying module (in js) for html and I want to provide a generic `query(selector)` function supporting both, css selectors and XPath selectors as string argument.

Regardless of how each kind of selection is done, my problem here is how to identify whether a given string is an xpath or a css selector. We can assume that the function would be something like this:

```
function query(selector){
   selectorKind = identifySelectorKind(selector); // I want to know how to code this particular function

   if(selectorKind==="css") return queryCss(selector);
   if(selectorKind==="xPath") return queryXPath(selector); //Assume both functions exists and work
}
```

My first approach (given my limited knowledge of xPath queries) was to identify the query kind by checking if the first character is `/` (here I am assuming all relevant xPath queries begin with `/`)

So, `identifySelectorKind` would go a bit like this:

```js
function identifySelectorKind(selector){
    if (selector[0] === "/") return "xPath";
    else return "css";
}
```

Note that I don't need to validate neither css nor xpath selectors, I only need an unambiguous way to differentiate them. Would this logic be enough? (in other words, all xPath selectors begin with `/` and no css selector begins the same way?), if not, is there a better way or some considerations I may want to know?

Answer (score 2):

You can't necessarily. For example, `*` is a valid xpath and a valid css selector, but it matches a different set of elements in each.

Comment: What's the difference between css `*`, xpath `*` and `//*` ?

Comment: css `*` and xpath `//*` match every element in the tree, xpath `*` matches child elements of the context node.

Comment: Would my assumptions be valid if all the queries are intended to work like in css (without context node)?

Comment: An xpath that matched the same elements independently of what the context node is, would have to start with a `/`, yes.

Comment: On reflection, there may be one case where a context node independent xpath doesn't start with a `/`. When it starts with `ancestor-or-self::`. For example, in an HTML document, `ancestor-or-self::node()//body` will match the body element regardless of what the context node is.

Comment: That's the kind of cases I want to know. What would the difference be between `ancestor-or-self::node()//body` and simply `//body`?

Comment: As far as I know, nothing at all. It would be the user's choice which one they used. While it would be odd for a human user to freely choose the longer variant, it could result from programmatic logic that built the xpath.

Comment: thanks, I guess I could either document that case (I'm just planning on supporting simple xpath global queries) or handle it separately

Answer (score 0):

If you're absolutely sure your XPath selector will always begin with `/`, then yes, it's fine. Note that an XPath selector doesn't have to begin with a `/`, but if yours always selects from the root, then it's fine.

Comment: Well, I'm not 100% sure, I would like to know the cases on which an xpath queries wouldn't start by / or //, considering all are DOM queries

Comment: @angrykoala, Xpath selectors can also start with `(` so like: https://duckduckgo.com and open web inspector console, enter: `$x(\`//*[contains(translate(text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), ${"Duck".toLowerCase()})]\`)` which matches all elements containing "duck" (case-insensitive). but when elements are nested in others, we often want the deepest (last matching) by wrapping the query in `()` and appending `[last()]` like `$x(\`(//*[contains(translate(text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), ${"Duck".toLowerCase()})])[last()]\`)[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Searching only for `/` won't be enough, for sure!

Exemple CSS selector (that will be a false positive):
`nav [itemtype="https://schema.org/BreadcrumbList"]`

I'm writing also a utility function to either use querySelector or xpath, and need to differenciate the 2.

The problem here is that both syntax can have arbitrary strings in it:
`xpath: //*[contains(text(),"string")]`
`css: *[some-attr="string"]`

...so it's always possible to have, whatever char you use to descriminate, in both syntax. (A xpath string in css is valid, and so a css string in xpath):
`xpath: //*[contains(text(),"a:hover:not(xpath)")]`
`css: *[xpath-attr="fuuu/xpath/also//here/*"]`

The quick and dirty solution I found is to cut out first all the quoted strings, and then test for xpath only char (actually `/` or `@`).

```js
const isXpath = str=>
    /[\/@]/.test(                     // find / or @ in
        str.split(/['"`]/)            // cut on any quote
            .filter( (s,i)=> !(i%2) ) // remove 1 on 2
            .join('')                 // string without quotes
    )


isXpath( 'nav [itemtype="https://schema.org/BreadcrumbList"] [itemtype="https://schema.org/ListItem"]' )
//> false 
// Actually search chars on "nav [itemtype=] [itemtype=]"
```

> /!\ Note this is not perfect, and some cases will be confusing like the exemples given in this discussion `*` or `div` will fall back to CSS (isXpath = false). You may perfect quoted string cut out (what about escaped quotes?) and then xpath chars...